# How to compare elements of a vector against each other? C++

Tags: c++, vector, size, element

I am supposed to read some data (specifically string datatype) and store each element in a vector. Now I have to check if any of the different strings that were inputted match in size, and if they do I have to see if there are any matching letters. Now my question is how do I compare what's inside the vector (first the size and then the different letters). Is it possible? 
Say I have 
HELLO
and
HELLA
They have the same size, and 4 letters that match.
This is what I am trying to accomplish. 
The code that I have does not work given my ignorance about the matter.
Thank you in advance.

```
vector <string> myVector;

//insert data insdide of the vector

myVector.push_back("Hello");
myVector.push_back("Hello");
myVector.push_back("Hello2");
myVector.push_back("Hello3");
myVector.push_back("Hello4");



//This is wrong 

for (unsigned int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++) {

    if (myVector[i].size == myVector[i+1].size()){
        cout << "SAME SIZE" << endl;
}

}



return 0;
```

Comment: Change `.size` to `.size()`. Also when `i` reaches its max value, you will try to access a non-existent element (you need to fix that)

Comment: It seems you need a double loop: `for (const auto& w1 : myVector) {for (const auto& w2 : myVector) {/*..*/} }` or with iterator/index to compare different element.

Comment: Thank you guys, it seems to be working. Also, how do I can even get to the single character?  Say I want to print the first letter of "HELLO"  (H)through the vector, how can I do that syntax wise? 
Thank you for your suggestions
@Valentin & Jarod42

Answer (score 0):

You just have make a simple mistake for size() function and you are trying to access the element which is not present by using i+1 for last iteration.
So just change your for loop just as below

```
for (unsigned int i = 1; i < myVector.size(); i++) 
{
    if (myVector[i].size() == myVector[i-1].size()) // .size() should be used
    {
        cout << "SAME SIZE" << endl;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. But how can I access a single character inside of the string?
 @S_Madankar

Comment: Basically String is nothing but a character array. So u can access the single character of a string stored in vector as myVector[0][0] , myVector[0][1] : It will give you 1st character of 0th string and 2nd character of 0th string respectively. So as per your program input myVector[0][0] gives 'H', myVector[4][5] gives '4'

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way of writing it:

```
// returns true if @param s1 and @param s2 are equal in letters
bool isEqual(const string& s1, const string& s2) {
   if(s1.size() != s2.size())
       return false;
   bool equal = false;
    // iterates over all the characters in s1  and s2 and compare them
    for(auto ch1 = s1.cbegin(), ch2 = s2.cbegin(); ch1 != s1.cend(),ch2!= s2.cend(); ch1++, ch2++) {
        if(*ch1 == *ch2)
           equal = true;
        else
           return false;
    }
    return equal;
}

// type of iter is vector<string>::const_iterator meaning it can only read the value
    for (auto iter = myVector.cbegin(); iter != myVector.cend() - 1; iter++){
       if(isEqual(*iter, *(iter + 1)))
          std::cout << *iter << " equal " << *(iter + 1) << endl;
       else
          std::cout << *iter << " different " << *(iter + 1) << endl;
    }
```

Here, I used iterators(*you should write code in modern C++, avoid using subscript*).

Comment: Please can you add the reason for avoiding subscripts? Is it based on aesthetic sense (idiomatic C++) or is there any implication for performance?